# Choose font sizes for tag cloud (rails3)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, fonts, cluster-analysis, tag-cloud

I would like to set font sizes for tags based on rating. This is what my sample ratings look like:

```
206 82 25 24 25 19 8 5 0 3 2 1 6 1 1 0 32 6 3 -1 112 31 6 8 2 24 18 2 2 1
1 1 2 6 67 35 37 25 0 1 7 8 2 3 0 1 2 1 -2 8 19 -2 1 1 -3 -4 6 1 1 8 11 3
1 3 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 -1 0 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 0 -5
-1 2 2
```

I've tried using k-means clustering [(gem)](https://github.com/reddavis/K-Means) but I can't seem to pick the right number of centroids because my ratings vary from case to case. Also, I'm not sure what font range to use. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Just a note: a gem like `acts-as-taggable-on-steroids` generates tag clouds for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find an algorithm for font sizes using logarithmic scaling based on the number of occurrences of each tag:
http://blogs.dekoh.com/dev/2007/10/29/choosing-a-good-font-size-variation-algorithm-for-your-tag-cloud/

Comment: How do you determine the minimum and maximum font sizes this way?

Comment: You set the font size via `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. In my script I use CSS classes s1 through s5, so I have 5 sizes. Here `min` and `max` is the number of minimum/maximum appearance of any tag: `1 + ((5-1)*(Math.log(count)-Math.log(min))/(Math.log(max)-Math.log(min))).round`. Caveat: do not divide by zero in some cases. Font sizes are 8pt through 14pt bold.

Answer (score 0):

Try i2ui for this issue:

1. Define font range.
2. Set up the rates for tags.

   ```
   <div data-i2="css:[{fontSize:'8px'},{fontSize:'25px'}]">
       <span data-i2="rate:1">Word1</span>
       <span data-i2="rate:82">Word2</span>
       <span data-i2="rate:-5">Word3</span>
       <span data-i2="rate:12">Word4</span>
   </div>
   ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x4558/